# Addressing Console.app messages on badly installed and removed software

Tags: launchd, macos, console

- Ever since I upgraded to 10.7, my computer has been acting funny, I lost my PostgreSQL installation so tried to install it again using the postgres 9.1 dmg from the postgres website. The installation halted. I've also removed all postgres installations from the computer in the hope of doing a "clean" install; but still I can't get it to install.
- About Akamai, it's a license/download tool that is shipped with AutoDesk (autoCAD) products. I've had AutoCAD trial installed but have since uninstalled it but still get the console error message.

I used AppCleaner I think to remove the apps.

The console.app messages that appear every 10 seconds or so:

```
11-10-01 11:37:02.534 AM com.edb.launchd.postgresql-9.0: 2011-10-01 14:37:02 GMT FATAL:  could not open lock file "postmaster.pid": Permission denied
11-10-01 11:37:02.535 AM com.apple.launchd: (com.edb.launchd.postgresql-9.0[2248]) Exited with code: 1
11-10-01 11:37:02.535 AM com.apple.launchd: (com.edb.launchd.postgresql-9.0) Throttling respawn: Will start in 10 seconds
11-10-01 11:37:06.645 AM com.apple.launchd.peruser.502: (com.akamai.client.plist[2252]) Bug: launchd_core_logic.c:4655 (24984):13
```

### EDIT

I've managed to remove the akamai process using Lignon, but still have the issue with postgres

Comment: What do you mean by lose Postgres install - the Lion upgrade only deletes things in Apple's directories not /usr/local and such like

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get rid of the Console.app message by entering the following command in Terminal:

```
sudo launchctl unload /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.edb.launchd.postgresql-9.0
```

That should unload the postgresql daemon.

Answer (score 0):

check if pgAgent is also running separate process. If yes then execute this command:

```
sudo launchctl unload /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.edb.launchd.pgagent.plist
```

and let your postgresql keep running.

Comment: How would one check for pgAgent?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for this, got me on track but for me it was:

```
sudo launchctl unload /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.edb.launchd.pgbouncer.plist
```